# not getting access token or too many redirects

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, access-token, restfb

According to this [page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/#app-login) I am setting the url to get access_token. Below is my redirectUri string and urlForAccessToken string respectively.

```
String redirectUri = "http://xxxx.mine.nu:8081/myfacebookapp/myfbapp";

String urlForAccessToken = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id="+apiKey+"&redirect_uri="+redirectUri+"&scope=email,read_stream";
```

My site URL and app domain in facebook (where we set the basics of Apps) is:

```
site URL: http://xxxx.mine.nu:8081/myfacebookapp/myfbapp
App domain: xxxx.mine.nu
```

Now, the problem is when I am doing a response.sendRedirect(urlForAccessToken); from the servlet I am getting below error:

```
The web page at http://xxxx.mine.nu:8081/myfacebookapp/myfbapp?code=xxx#base_domain=xxxx.mine.nu
 has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site
 or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly
 a server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer.
```

I cleared the cookies but no success.

Would someone guide me as to what I am doing wrong. I am just trying to get the access token and would like to access the basic as well as extended data of facebook users.

My platform is Java and I am using restFB to communicate with the graph API.

below is my servlet code:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("<br><h4>We are getting Facebook data</h4>");
    response.sendRedirect(urlForAccessToken);
    String access_token = (String)request.getParameter("access_token");
    out.println("<br>code: " + code);
    try{
        FacebookClient facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(access_token);
        //user = facebookClient.fetchObject("xxxxxxxxxxxx", User.class);
        out.println("<br>User: " + user.getName());
    }catch(FacebookException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

An early response is appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was wrong?  I'm getting the same issue with one particular user.