# PHP-SDK too many redirects

Tags: php, facebook

I'm using the [PHP-SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk) for Facebook and got the example to work on my localhost. However, when building a script on a server the script stays quite busy with redirecting from my script to facebook and back. (Error: Fout 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS):)

It seems that many more people have got this issue ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8771833/not-getting-access-token-or-too-many-redirects), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200749/url-has-too-many-redirects-facebook-wont-be-able-to-scrape-this-url-until-the), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10573199/facebook-connect-gives-a-redirect-loop), [here](http://www.zymic.com/forum/lofiversion/index.php/t24244.html)). Though, I can't find a clear answer what goes wrong.

Redirect to facebook (response 302):

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=166958180001271&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdomain.com%2Fscripts%2FGateway.php%3Faction%3DAllowFacebookAccessAction%26app%3D14&state=0dbc178a375595da4751265a7147c01e#_=_
```

Redirect to mydomain (response 302):

```
http://domain.com/scripts/Gateway.php?action=AllowFacebookAccessAction&app=14&state=0dbc178a375595da4751265a7147c01e&code=AQD-dTeyns0OWpGb_PzfHxUy2iRmpc1XgP6Q24DDRX8MiRTE10lV-b-aSNIlOLVHk576vRs3H8Pf9n0kGwU827MrkzUCUoQGFGEQBkkOJnCy9zb6hZs7TVBsKL2iSuZIhDjLsCOPeKy3zfb37Q6LGhtMICCdB_IQAvU0uRvAkSAX8tdVJ65PEv8imx-2yvLaMoGJleZwKogh7m03vlhV8hJk#_=_
```

Part of the code that creates this issue

```
...            
    $facebook = new FacebookApi(array(
            'appId' => $app->getProperty('apiKey'),
            'secret' => $app->getProperty('secretKey'),
        ));
    $user = $facebook->getUser();
    if (!$user) {    
        header('location: ' . $facebook->getLoginUrl());
        exit;
    }
...
```

UPDATE:

I ruled out that its a server setting. I was able to run the original example script on that server.

Comment: Sometimes this has to do with disabled cookies.

Comment: @OlafDietsche unfortunately not this time.

Comment: Check your server's error log. The Facebook SDK does log _some_ error messages there. `getUser()` tries to verify that the `state` parameter (= anti-CSRF token) is equal to what it expects, which might fail in some cases (e.g. if you have called `$facebook->setAppId()` to change the app ID _after_ instantiation); also it tries to exchange the `code` parameter for an actual access token, which also might fail in some cases (e.g. if the URL you're on when you call `getUser()` is different from the one you were when you called `getLoginUrl()`).

Comment: is that 'FacebookApi' class from the current API? I thought it was 'Facebook'? have you made other modifications to the API which might break the [Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/) flow?

Comment: @lanzz the logs show one error `[Thu Nov 08 09:48:34 2012] [error] [client 82.204.37.70] OAuthException: Invalid
OAuth access token signature.` I didn't change the appId or the urls concerning `getUser()` or `getLoginUrl()`.

Comment: @lgy I only changed the name of the the class `Facebook` to `FacebookApi`. A data class already has the same name and best option was to rename the class name of the facebook api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recheck your app `secret` in your app settings https://developers.facebook.com/apps otherwise dump the session

```
<?php print_r($_SESSION); ?>
```

And lint the token returned https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Pretty sure either the token is mangled or the secret.

If not, it's in code you haven't shown.

Comment: Damn, this was *%& N00bish of me. The secret was wrong and never re-checked it :-s How foolish! Thanks any way!