# Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many redirects. Using PHP SDK for facebook

Tags: php, facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP-SDK too many redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13065649/php-sdk-too-many-redirects)

Am trying to save sessions of facebook login to database and using localhost as HOST(using PHP SDK for facebook). Below is my code.

```
<?php

require_once 'facebook/facebook.php';
require 'config/fbconfig.php';
require 'config/functions.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
            'appId' => APP_ID,
            'secret' => APP_SECRET,
            ));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) 
{
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }

    if (!empty($user_profile )) {
        # User info ok? Let's print it (Here we will be adding the login and     registering routines)

        $username = $user_profile['name'];
         $uid = $user_profile['id'];
           $email = $user_profile['email'];
            $user = new User();
        $userdata = $user->checkUser($uid, 'facebook',     $username,$email,$twitter_otoken,$twitter_otoken_secret);
        if(!empty($userdata)){
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['id'] = $userdata['id'];
    $_SESSION['oauth_id'] = $uid;

            $_SESSION['username'] = $userdata['username'];
    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
            $_SESSION['oauth_provider'] = $userdata['oauth_provider'];
            header("Location: home.php");
        }
    } else {
        # For testing purposes, if there was an error, let's kill the script
        die("There was an error.");
    }
 } else {
    # There's no active session, let's generate one
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array( 'scope' => 'email'));
            header("Location: " . $login_url);
 }
?>
```

home.php looks like below..

```
<?php

//Always place this code at the top of the Page
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    // Redirection to login page twitter or facebook
    header("location: index.php");
}
else
{
echo '<h1>Welcome</h1>';
echo 'id : ' . $_SESSION['id'];
echo '<br/>Name : ' . $_SESSION['username'];
echo '<br/>Email : ' . $_SESSION['email'];
echo '<br/>You are login with : ' . $_SESSION['oauth_provider'];
echo '<br/>Logout from <a href="logout.php?logout">' . $_SESSION['oauth_provider'] .     '</a>';
}
?>
```

But the browser(chrome) is throwing below error

```
 Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many redirects.
```

I have tried clearing all cookies but to no avail. Let me understand how to handle this error, or if there is a code to be changed. Also i have tried looking into forums for the error, but they were not so explanatory, for it might be am new to this area.

Answer (score 2):

The error means there is an infinite loop of redirections.

Seems like index.php is redirecting to home.php, and then home.php is redirecting back to index.php, in an infinite loop..

In your index.php and home.php, check the value of `$_SESSION['id']` before each `if()` and inside each `if()`, since it's the main variable that will break the loop.